# howto create/load a jks file with the java keytool for jetty?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, keytool

while i was setting up jetty with a ssl connector i noticed that i need to set a keystorepath.

```
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(EmbeddedServer.class.getResource("/keystore.jks").toExternalForm());
```

So i tried to create a keystore.jks file with javas keytool. With commands like this:

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

But somehow i never endet up with a .jks file.

Can someone help me generate this jks file?

Or are there alternate solutions to setup ssl for jetty without a .jks file?

UPDATE:

I was able to generate a jks file but now the question is how do i load it?

My code so far:

```
Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(9999);

HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());


SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("./resources/server.jks"); 

sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("123456");
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("123456");
```

Comment: JKS stands for Java Key Store.  It's not a Jetty specific thing, You'll definitely need a JKS format keystore file when working with any Java server or client that uses SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i figured this out by my own:

Create JKS:

```
keytool.exe -genkeypair -keystore server.jks
```

Load it:

```
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("./resources/server.jks");
```

Comment: If you want to use `keytool ... -alias client` then you'll also need `sslContextFactory.setAlias("client");`